# Jpg images are not displayed in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Images are displayed in png format but images are not displayed in jpg format.
The problem was not with any particular plugin

[image]

Comment: We need more details to be able to help. I'd start by looking into your browser's developer tools see if it detects any errors.

Comment: http://izi-to.ir/ this my website. What more information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try #1:**
Try to set your [Permalinks](http://izi-to.ir/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) to "Post name". I also think that you need to set the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" in your [General](http://izi-to.ir/wp-admin/options-general.php) settings to the right URL of your website (ONLY if it is not set properly).

**Try #2:**
I think you need to re-upload your photos one-by-one. All the image paths have problem. Some of it doesn't have src, the other images are hosted to other websites which doesn't exists.

1. [Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwSQ.jpg)
2. [Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFkAe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You use svg images this wrong path http://prntscr.com/xyk36i just change path from jpg images.

Comment: I think not all images are displayed except png format

Comment: Just check your path to images, all wrong http://prntscr.com/xykhvs
The problem is not jpg

Comment: How should I do this?

Comment: You need to contact the theme developer or dig into the code yourself and look for an error